# socket.timeout mongoDB pyspark

Tags: python, mongodb, timeout, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to execute a python file in SPARK using a mongoDB connector. The python file do a query to get some data from mongoDB and them process this data with a map operation in SPARK.

The the execution stops getting this error message: "socket.timeout: timed out", while the map operation is being executed. That is the output I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ana/computational_tools_for_big_data/project/review_analysis.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       bad_reviews = reviews_1.rdd.map(lambda r: r.text).collect()   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 777, in
>   collect   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 142, in
>   _load_from_socket   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line
>   139, in load_stream   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line
>   156, in _read_with_length   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line
>   543, in read_int   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 384, in
>   read
>       data = self._sock.recv(left) socket.timeout: timed out

I get this problem because the file I am querying it is very big 2.3GB, I tried the same with a file of 1GB and it is the same problem but it is works with a smaller file of 400MB.

Is it possible to change the timeout or something to make it work?
Is there any other way to process a big amount of data faster?

Answer (score -2):

Your issue is the socket connection is taking more time than the timeout specified.
Refer this document to change the timeouts and other settings.

The property you want to change

> **socketTimeoutMS:** (integer or None) Controls how long (in milliseconds) the driver will wait for a response after sending an
> ordinary (non-monitoring) database operation before concluding that a
> network error has occurred. Defaults to None (no timeout).
>
> E.g. MongoClient('localhost', 27017, socketTimeoutMS=6000)

Of course based on how much time it actually takes for 2.3GB file transfer, you might want to go above one minute (6000), I mentioned in the example.

Documentation of MongoClient

> https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

Documentation of PyMongo MongoClient

> http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html

Comment: This is pymongo client. @Ana is looking for pyspark mongodb connector config setting.